# Using google api to retrieve map and update user location by specific interval

Tags: android, api, google-maps, location

Hi I am doing a `maps` `activity` use to retrieve the current user `location` and update the location base on specific interval. But I can not get the function to update the current location (as user moving)

Here is my field declaration:

```
//Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    Location location;

    //Object to store Coordinates
    LatLng latLng;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    //Constant
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
```

My activity body

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
        buttonSave = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
        buttonView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);


        // Create the location request
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        settingsRequest();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

My function to check Location setting (use to enable location on devices)

```
public void settingsRequest()
{
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
        final Status status = result.getStatus();
        final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.

                // Request location updates;
                startLocationUpdates();

                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                // a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

}

My `startLocationUpdates()`

```
// Trigger new location updates at interval
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        // Request location updates
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,
                locationRequest,this);
    }
```

I get the error on the function,  `startLocationUpdates()`, dont know why. I just want to update to location by specify interval and update the `latitude` and `longtitude` variable (for  moving the camera map for example). Any help is much appreciate,

Answer (score 0):

THanks for the advice. I can get the updated location by interval by this function (need to check the permission before running, think only for android 6)

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);

            return;
        }else {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,
                    locationRequest, this);
        }
    }
```